# modifying htaccess for localhost with a custom port

Tags: htaccess, localhost, local-installation

I have a live instance of wordpress which I'm attempting to spin up on my local machine using xampp. A brief summary of steps to where I'm currently at:

1. configured xampp to use a custom port (8012)
2. downloaded the latest files and database
3. added the entire public_html file to my new directory ('support') within xampp: `C:\xampp\htdocs\support`
4. Modified all instances of the live URL to my localhost URL `localhost:8012/support` in the database
5. Uploaded the database to phpmyadmin
6. updated the `wp-config` with the traditional username,pw and new `localhost:8012` URL
7. made a few slight tweaks to the `php.ini` files and phpmyadmin `config.default` file so there isn't any limits

...and boom! stuck. when i attempt to load `localhost:8012/support`, I should be greeted with a login page. Instead, I'm getting a continual load and then timeout.

I've had this working before, and remember that I have to modify the `.htaccess` file but every attempt at updating this file in the rewrite module section, is resulting in the same outcome. I'm 99% certain this is the issue. This is what it's currently set to - any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /support/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .localhost:8012/support [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've updated both the `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule` with several different versions (including `http://` and including `index.php`), but still breaks/doesn't load. I've no prior knowledge around this, so a little help as to what value should go here should go here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why it's a necessity to use a custom port? It almost seems like THAT is the problem that needs fixing ;)

Comment: port 80 in use elsewhere and need to keep that separate unfortunately.

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the _basic_ WordPress `.htaccess` file if you are accessing the site via a different port. Do you have a custom `.htaccess` file of some kind? The `.htaccess` code you posted is invalid and will never match (it just won't do anything). If you are getting a "timeout" then it suggests you have a problem with your server/DNS.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'd change my .conf file to state the correct port if you've got access to that.

For instance.

```
<VirtualHost *:8012>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/LOCATION OF FILES
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/LOCATION OF FILES>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Then i'd restart apache. (if you are using apache that is)